# Custom toolbar location XP

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

A few years ago Umber Ferrule wrote that the toolbars in the taskbar are defined in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams.
```

This looks very plausible but cannot be the entire story.  Deleting this key will in no way affect the taskbar and on rebooting the system the key magically reappears.

Why do I want to know?  Simple.  I would like to export the key to a reg. file as a convenient backup.

Comment: Can't get it to work.  This is what I did: 1) export the key to OldToolbar.reg 2) delete one of the items in a custom toolbar 3) execute OldToolbar.reg 4) On reboot the deleted item has not reappeared. In case importing a reg file is different from executing it, I did the experiment using both methods.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The fact that the key is restored on reboot after having been deleted must mean that the information is saved in a location which has precedence over the key.  It is that location which needs to be saved/restored.  But where is it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 locations that make up the whole of the toolbars for XP.
One is the positional data for the locations of the toolbars, and the icons order in the toolbars, which is in the location of the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\`
**The other location is the folder itself that stores the icon items, actual file items**, the desktop quick bar location, or the user created toobar folder location.

For making multiple Toolbars and interleaved toolbars, I always create a folder celled "toolbars" in the root of the system disk. Inside there I make sub-folders that hold the icons that will be displayed in the multiple toolbars.

Exporting the registry data will save the positional data, saving the folders is done with a regular system backup/imaging/cloneing operation.
If the problem is manually removing a Toolbar Icon item, your manually removing the file from the folder itself.  If the problem is losing a whole toolbar, it comes from removing the folder itself.

The reason for saving the registry seperate is:  If you or the system closes the toolbars, or ruins the position, you can get that back.  If your changing the icon items in there (and therefore the files themselves), that is assumed to be a desired operation to keep.

Pablo678s problem was importing the registry , the registry is overwritten when the system saves the registry out.
Because  Toolbars in XP are integrated into the explorer. A person can taskend the explorer insert the key and re-start the explorer. instead of booting the machine, and having the registry overwritten again.

Notes:  This is similar to any regular folders, you have the real folder locations, and the position data for the folders opening is stored in the "Bags" in the registry.

Comment: This is very revealing.  Thank you.

I do something similar. Only difference is that I keep this folder on a removable drive. When I change a toolbar item via the visible toolbar on the taskbar, it is this folder "Toolbars" in the removable drive which changes, bearing out your explanation.

On a new computer software needed is installed using batch programs. This works fine except for the custom toolbars.  These have to be dragged manually onto the taskbar. Could I automate this process by executing the saved key in a batch program?  Does the key contain the address of my "Toolbar" folder?

Comment: I do not know, I never change my locations.  So your loosing the whole set, when the file locations change, hmmm.  You can batch a set of registry entries, batch import.

Comment: I don't change the location of my "Toolbars" either. It's always in the same place on the removable drive. Question is whether on executing the reg file in the batch program, the system will pick up the address of the "Toolbars" file when no toolbars are yet in place.  I'll have to test and let you know the results.

Comment: No, this doesn't work.  Here's what I did.
1) save the key 2) Delete the on-screen toolbars 3) Reboot 4) As expected, the toolbars did not show up 5) Import the key 6) Reboot 7) The toolbars did not show up and had to be restored by dragging from the "Toolbars" folder.  Whatever the key may hold, it clearly does not hold the address of the "Toolbars" folder.  Disappointing.

Comment: OK, here's the problem: the key does indeed contain the addresses of custom toolbars but it is not possible to permanently import a saved key from a previous session. Why? Because the status of the current taskbar is copied into the key no matter what you have imported overwriting your precious backup. How do I know? Simple. Import the saved key and then switch off the power!!! Reboot and ignore the blue screen of death. Hey presto, there is your saved taskbar, but I really must find a more elegant solution. Can you suggest any?

Comment: Something in that is confusing, because if you dont get a clean shutdown/reboot the registry is not saved out at all. There are also the other control sets, which it can revert to if the current control set has fails.  Are you looking for a method to have the present configurations saved even when the system fails, and therefore does not save the registry out properly?

Comment: That's right, the registry is not saved and that's why the imported key survives.  If you shut down properly the imported key gets overwritten. Now this was just an experiment to see if the address of the custom toolbar really exists in the key. It does. So the question still is: What batch code will put a custom toolbar onto the taskbar? The registry won't help because it only defines the taskbar at boot-up. To answer your question: No, I want a batch script which puts one of my predefined custom toolbars onto the task bar, just as you can do manually with the "New Toolbar ..." option.

Comment: Uhhhhhh (thinking). Toolbars in XP are integrated into the explorer. not sure how that would help, but you can taskend the explorer insert the key and re-start the explorer. instead of going all the way out.

Comment: Good thinking!! 1) exported taskbar with two custom toolbars. 2) wiped both toolbars off the taskbar. 3) Rebooted to make sure that they were gone from the toolbar although this step is unnecessary 4) Imported the saved key 5) Killed explorer: Both toolbars are back!! What happens is that explorer cannot be permanently killed. It automatically pops back but in doing so clearly kickstarts the registry key. Success! Thank you. Now to convert this into a batch script.

Comment: In the rare instance of needing to batch the explorer gone in XP, i used >Kill /f explorer . then toss a pause in as needed, before or after doing the other things. Kill.exe was a microsoft utility, not original to the system, there is some taskkill thing in there too. that method does not re-start the explorer. the explorer restarts when it thinks it crashed.

Comment: It only requires two lines of script G:\Toolbars\TBSettings.reg and
G:\taskill.exe /explorer.exe. But I was lucky. In my experiments I used a portable proggie called "taskill" to kill the process which is different from the XP command "taskkill". Taskill works, Taskkill does not and neither does the Task Manager, both of which wipe out everything on the screen. I have no idea why. Maybe taskill crashes explorer while the Task Manager really gets rid of it ... permanently.  Who knows.

Comment: @techie007
also: to Mokubai. mpy, Shakehar and Scott
I am sorry that you guys didn't understand the problem. Fortunately Psycogeek did, and the problem got solved. I'm grateful to him but you can now close the thread if you so desire.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you already have a custom toolbar which you wish to transfer to another computer or simply back up in case it gets damaged.

The following batch script line will save the settings in a reg file which can be executed when the toolbar has to be restored. The `/E` parameter directs REGEDIT to export.

```
REGEDIT /E D:\TBSettings.reg "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Desktop"
```

To restore the toolbar you need [TASKILL, a freeware portable program](http://www.ozemail.com.au/~nulifetv/freezip/freeware/).

It is similar to the windows program TASKKILL but less drastic and it is needed to kill explorer.exe which restores the taskbar when the computer is turned off.

- Set TASKILL on the windows path

  ```
  XCOPY "D:\taskill.exe"   C:\WINDOWS
  ```
- Kill explorer

  ```
  Taskill explorer.exe
  ```
- Restore toolbar settings with the reg file saved in the backup

  ```
  D:\TBSettings.reg
  ```

Comment: Thanks slhck. That's what I wanted in the first place but couldn't because the question had been closed.